# NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification not working

Tags: ios

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
             addObserver:self selector:@selector(localeDidChange)
             name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification object:nil]; 
 }

-(void)localeDidChange{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ALERT"
                                                    message:@"languagechange"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

 }
```

I'm changing region from iphone setting but localeDidChange method never fired please help.

Comment: same issue here